# How can I tidy up my JSON to reduce gaps and decrease file size?

Tags: python, json

I am writing to a JSON with variable data, at the moment it is way too long, like hundreds of thousands of lines. I think can significantly reduce file size if I can remove gaps...

At the moment i write to my json like so

```
for num in num_list:
                datalog['build'].append({
                    'Number': num,
                    'Code' : L 
                })
                json.dump(datalog, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=False, ensure_ascii=False, separators=(',', ':'))
```

how can i edit the above `json.dump` to go from this;

```
{
    "build":[
        {
            "Num":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "Code":[
                {
                    "text":"0515: xxx"
                },
                {
                    "text":""
                },
                {
                    "text":""
                },
                {
                    "text":""
                },
```

to this;

```
{
    "build":[
        {
            "Num":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            "Code":[{"text":"0515: xxx"},{"text":""},{"text":""},{"text":""},
```

Comment: I don't think that will give him the output he wants

Comment: If the whole goal is minimal filesize, I'd say look into JSON minifiers like [ujson](https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I'll have a look, would like to keep solution as simple as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the python json default module you can't choose which gap you keep or remove. You can put `indent=0` which will delete all gaps and reduce the file size but make it unreadable for humans.

If interoperability with another language is not a problem you can use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or [mashall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html).

Comment: Thanks this is good, I used 'indent=None'  which is what i was after

Answer (score 0):

Since 'Code' is a list of dicts with 1 entry only it can be reduced to a list of strings.

```
 "Code":[{"text":"0515: xxx"},{"text":""},{"text":""},{"text":""}]
```

Can be converted to:

```
 "Code":["0515: xxx","","",""]
```